# My Python project won't work on different IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I've created a Python project that works fantastic on my daily basis on my work computer. I made it using Conda/Spyder.

I decided to move and make some changes to the same the project but on my Home Windows 10 Computer using SublimeText the lastest version and I get a lot of Traceback Errors, NameErros.

I was curious so I decided to use Ubuntu using Visual Code. I've got different errors.

So my question is the following: Is it normal that this happens or my code is garbage that only my work computer understands?
My app using the Tkinter GUI and when I played with Tkinter on Ubuntu using VC looks like the syntax changes on Ubuntu. for example. On windows is as simple as using and Ubuntu won't accept that apparently.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

while on Ubuntu is maybe something like this

```
from tkinter import *
root = ttk.Tk()
root.mailoop()
```

I'm new in this kind of topics and programming so I have a lot of questions.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Sublime Text, VSCode, or any other editor or IDE. It has to do (most likely) with different Python versions, different installed packages, and different versions of the same package. Make sure your environments are all the same.

Comment: On your work computer, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Then on your home Windows and Ubuntu computers, create new virtualenvs and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Feel free to prune `requirements.txt`, as it creates a list of *all* your installed modules, not just the ones used in your project. This is why virtualenvs are such a great idea.

Comment: Many stuff here that I do not understand. What is your entire traceback. Then there is no `ttk.Tk()`, then you are not even importing `ttk` then how is it defined....

Answer (score 1):

Just like MattDMo wrote, this issues can be the following:

1. Different Python packages.
2. Different package versions
3. Different operating systems (some of the packages you use might not work on windows or linux or visa versa).

How to solve all of this?
Use [Virtual Environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) with requirements.txt and make sure that all the packages you use are global for both Linux and Windows.

4. Also possible- poor project layout that might cause problems with PYTHONPATH. Hard to tell without you adding more information